# Use PHP to convert SVG to PCB file format

Tags: php, dom, svg

I have one file which has coordinates and would like to extract these coordinates into variables `x1`, `x2`, `y1`, `y2` so that I can then get center lines using y = y2-y1 and x=x2-x1

For example, I want to convert file data like this:

```
points="94.08955764770508,275.3258819580078 99.92155838012695,275.3258819580078 99.92155838012695,281.16587829589844 94.08955764770508,281.16587829589844"
```

Into variables like this:

```
x1 = 94.08955764770508
y1 = 275.3258819580078
x2 = 99.92155838012695
y2 = 275.3258819580078
```

Here is the code that I have been trying:

```
$line = '<polygon id="svg_806" fill-rule="nonzero" fill="black" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="0" points="94.08955764770508,275.3258819580078 99.92155838012695,275.3258819580078 99.92155838012695,281.16587829589844 94.08955764770508,281.16587829589844 "/>';

if (strpos($line,'<polygon') !== false) {
    $a = 1;

for ($i=0; $i <= 6; $i++) {
    $cordinates = explode('points="', $line);
    $cordinates = substr($cordinates[$i], 0, strpos($cordinates[$i], '"'));

foreach(explode(' ', $cordinates) as $value) {
$parts = explode(",", $value);
    echo trim($parts[0])."<br/>".trim($parts[1])."<br/>";

  }
}
}
```

Comment: you shouldn't be using string operations on what is essentially an XML document. use DOM, then some xpath to get all the polygons, then get the polygon's points attribute.

Answer (score 0):

here's a quick and dirty solution which works:

```
<?php
$line = '<polygon id="svg_806" fill-rule="nonzero" fill="black" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="0" points="94.08955764770508,275.3258819580078 99.92155838012695,275.3258819580078 99.92155838012695,281.16587829589844 94.08955764770508,281.16587829589844 "/>';
$xml = simplexml_load_string($line);
$ps = explode(" ", $xml->attributes()->points);

$points = array();
$i = 1;
foreach($ps as $point){
    $exploded =  explode(",", $point);
    $points["x".$i] = $exploded[0];
    $points["y".$i] = $exploded[1];
    $i++;
}

print_r($points);
?>
```

This leads to this output:

```
Array ( [x1] => 94.08955764770508 [y1] => 275.3258819580078 [x2] => 99.92155838012695 [y2] => 275.3258819580078 [x3] => 99.92155838012695 [y3] => 281.16587829589844 [x4] => 94.08955764770508 [y4] => 281.16587829589844 [x5] => [y5] => )
```

Now you can access the needed elements of the array with:
$points["x1"] $points["y1"] ...

Hope this helps

To answer the question in your comment, here is the solution:

```
$input = "2957 1620 1124 3836 1524 3836 1524 3684 1924 3684 3324 3838 3724 3838 584 3574";
$i = $count = 1;
$points = array();
$exploded = explode(" ", $input);
foreach ($exploded as $current){
    if($count % 2 == 1){
        //X
        $points["x".$i] = $current;
    }else{
        //y
        $points["y".$i] = $current;
        $i++;
    }
    $count++;
}
print_r($points);
```

leads to:

```
Array ( [x1] => 2957 [y1] => 1620 [x2] => 1124 [y2] => 3836 [x3] => 1524 [y3] => 3836 [x4] => 1524 [y4] => 3684 [x5] => 1924 [y5] => 3684 [x6] => 3324 [y6] => 3838 [x7] => 3724 [y7] => 3838 [x8] => 584 [y8] => 3574 )
```

Comment: My knowledge of PHP is not great...now all your code is working excellent...so svg drawing is successfuly converted to PCB file format and i im getting correct LINES and PADS in my PCB program from svg file. Now i would like to have php script that makes the following:      2957 1620
1124 3836
1524 3836
1524 3684
1924 3684
3324 3838
3724 3838
584 3574                                                                   i need to get x1=2957 y1=1620 x2=1124 y2=3836 x3=1524 y3=3836 x4=1524 y4=3684

Answer (score 0):

**Code:**

```
// Your SVG
$line = '<polygon id="svg_806" fill-rule="nonzero" fill="black" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="0" points="94.08955764770508,275.3258819580078 99.92155838012695,275.3258819580078 99.92155838012695,281.16587829589844 94.08955764770508,281.16587829589844 "/>';

// Parse SVG as XML and extract 'points' attribute
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($line);
$points = (string) $xml->attributes()->points;

// Parse points attribute
preg_match_all('/([^, ]+),([^, ]+)/', $points, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);

// Convert matches from regular expression to nice array
$point_coords = array_map(function($m) {
        return array('x' => (float) $m[1], 'y' => (float) $m[2]);
    }, $matches);

// Now you have array of points array('x' => float, 'y' => float)
echo var_export($point_coords);
```

**Output:**

```
array (
  0 =>
  array (
    'x' => 94.089557647705,
    'y' => 275.32588195801,
  ),
  1 =>
  array (
    'x' => 99.921558380127,
    'y' => 275.32588195801,
  ),
  2 =>
  array (
    'x' => 99.921558380127,
    'y' => 281.1658782959,
  ),
  3 =>
  array (
    'x' => 94.089557647705,
    'y' => 281.1658782959,
  ),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this code can help you:

```
<?php

// Your XML string
$xmlStr = '<polygon id="svg_806" fill-rule="nonzero" fill="black" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="0" points="94.08955764770508,275.3258819580078 99.92155838012695,275.3258819580078 99.92155838012695,281.16587829589844 94.08955764770508,281.16587829589844 "/>';

// Read the XML into and PHP object, making it ease to access structerd data
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlStr);

// Extracts the string inside "points" parameter in polygon (main) tag
$pointsStr = (string)$xml->attributes()->points;

// Breaks the string in pieces of space separated points, like "94.08955764770508,275.3258819580078"
$pointsArr = explode(' ', trim($pointsStr));

// The result array, each element is a point (an array with 2 positions)
$points = array();

foreach ($pointsArr as $pointStr) {
    // Reads the float data for each position using C-like sscanf
    list($x, $y) = sscanf($pointStr, '%f,%f');

    // Echo and save
    echo "Read point ($x, $y)<br>\n";
    $points[] = array($x, $y);
}

?>
```

It echoes:

> Read point (94.089557647705, 275.32588195801)
>   Read point (99.921558380127, 275.32588195801)
>   Read point (99.921558380127, 281.1658782959)
>   Read point (94.089557647705, 281.1658782959)

`$points` will be:

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    float(94.089557647705)
    [1]=>
    float(275.32588195801)
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    float(99.921558380127)
    [1]=>
    float(275.32588195801)
  }
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    float(99.921558380127)
    [1]=>
    float(281.1658782959)
  }
  [3]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    float(94.089557647705)
    [1]=>
    float(281.1658782959)
  }
}
```